# Creating a base_url(variable) in the config file - Laravel Config

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, config

I am currently migrating my .env settings to config files.

I have list of url's which I will be calling from the application. The BASE_URL will change, so I am looking to keep it as a variable..

In the .env file, I am able to call the BASE_URL as variable but in the config file, I am not getting any result.

> .env file

```
BASE_URL = www.url.com
URL1 = ${BASE_URL}/url1,
URL2 = ${BASE_URL}/url2,
URL3 = ${BASE_URL}/url3,
```

In Config Folder > Created url.php file

> url.php

```
<?php
return[
'BASE_URL' => 'www.url.com',
'URL1' => 'www.url.com/url1',
'URL2' => 'www.url.com/url2',
'URL3' => 'www.url.com/url3',
];
```

What I did(workaround) !!

```
<?php
    return[
    'URL1' => env('BASE_URL')'/url1',
    'URL2' => env('BASE_URL')'/url2',
    'URL3' => env('BASE_URL')'/url3',
    ];
```

I would like to know, is this the only solution or are any other better way. I would like to move every settings to the config file.

I had the same questoin while I was creating a laravel package. Hope an alternative solution could also be used for package development.

Comment: Missing commas in your return array. Also, how do you access those config variables?

Comment: Edited the question, I am getting the values of config in blade {{Config::get('config.URL1')}}

Comment: `{{Config::get('config.URL1')}}` is the wrong notation, it should be `{{Config::get('url.URL1')}}` as stated in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you correctly you want to have one base url in your config file and use that for other config variables in the same file. Since config files are `.php` you can use something like:

In `config/url.php`:

```
<?php

$baseURL = 'http://www.example.com';

return [
    'base_url' => $baseURL,
    'url1' => $baseURL . '/login',
    'url2' => $baseURL . '/about',
];
```

You can then access the variables using [Laravel's dot notation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/configuration). Remember that the part before the dot is the short name of the config file you used (`url.php`):

```
{{ Config::get('url.base_url') }}
{{ Config::get('url.url1') }}
{{ Config::get('url.url2') }}
```

Will output:

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/login
http://www.example.com/about
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this,

*.env*

```
BASE_URL = www.url.com
URL1 = ${BASE_URL}/url1
URL2 = ${BASE_URL}/url2
URL3 = ${BASE_URL}/url3
```

*config/url.php*

```
return[
  'URL1' => env('URL1','www.url.com/url1'),
  'URL2' => env('URL2','www.url.com/url2'),
  'URL3' => env('URL3','www.url.com/url3'),
];
```

and use config('url.URL1') to access config values

Comment: i am looking to keep the env variables independent from the config..